# Подгрузка контента при клике через ajax на WordPress?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, ajax

Вот HTML

```
<a href="#" class="lp_orange_pill" id="showSearchSteps">showSearchSteps</a>
<div id="quizAppend"></div>
```

Вот JavaScript

```
  $("#showSearchSteps").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      method: 'POST',
      success: function (response) {
        $("#quizAppend").append(response);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Ошибка при загрузки квиза');
      }
    });
  });
```

Вот код functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_load_quiz', 'ajax_load_quiz' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_load_quiz', 'ajax_load_quiz' );
function ajax_load_quiz(){
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){
        include(locate_template('/quiz_test.php'));
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка отправки";
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Вот quiz_test.php

```
<? echo "test"; ?>
```

При клике на #showSearchSteps выдает алертом "Ошибка отправки". не могу подгрузить в #quizAppend слово "test". Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

У вас action не указано в ajax-вызове. Потому ядро не находит ваш хук и возращает вам 400, что вызывает алерт "Ошибка отправки".

Надо так:

```js
    $.ajax({
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      action: 'load_quiz',
      method: 'POST',
      success: function (response) {
        $("#quizAppend").append(response);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Ошибка при загрузки квиза');
      }
    });
```

Это логично. Как по вашему коду WP должен угадать, какой хук ajax использовать?

Замечания.

1. Смысл `if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){` равен нулю, это условие всегда true в ajax.
2. Почитайте, [как следует создавать ajax-запросы в WP](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html). Ваш код - это дырка в безопасности, потому что нет nonce и проверки прав доступа. Кроме того, следует использовать `wp_send_json_success()` и `wp_send_json_error()`.

Comment: Все равно всплываает алерт(

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было сделать вот так

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: {
    action: 'ajax_load_quiz',
  },
  method: 'POST',
  success: function (response) {
    $("#quizAppend").append(response);
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('Ошибка при загрузки квиза');
  }
});
```

Comment: Да, правильно .